# Reducing Logical Expressions

Tags: logic, karnaugh-map

I am having trouble reducing a logical expression via logical equivalences. The expression is as follows:

```
~A~C~D + AB~C~D + ABD + ABC~D + A~B~C~D
```

Using a Karnaugh Map I am able to reduce the expression to AB + ~C~D.

The problem comes in that I am trying to reduce the expression using logical equivalences. There are two approaches I have tried:

```
~A~C~D + AB( ~C~D + D + C~D ) + A~B~C~D
~A~C~D + AB( D + ~D(~C + C) ) + A~B~C~D
~A~C~D + AB( ~D + D ) + A~B~C~D
~A~C~D + AB + A~B~C~D
```

By this method I am able to prove AB, but I cannot see how I would progress to solve ~C~D. The other method is as follows:

```
~C~D( ~A + AB + A~B) + ABD + ABC~D
~C~D( ~A + A( B + ~B ) ) + ABD + ABC~D
~C~D( ~A + A ) + ABD + ABC~D
~C~D + ABD + ABC~D
```

By this method I am able to prove ~C~D but I cannot see how I would progress to solve AB.

Is there a way to solve this is one fluid proof that I am not seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your result

```
~C~D + ABD + ABC~D
= ~C~D(True + AB) + AB(D + C~D)
= ~C~D + AB~C~D + AB(D+C~D)
= ~C~D + AB(~C~D + C~D + D)
= ~C~D + AB((~C + C)~D + D)
= ~C~D + AB.
```

Comment: Could you explain that first step off of my result? I still don't understand it.

Comment: ~C~D = ~C~D(True)
but True = True + AB. They're both true.
It's like A or AB is the same as A.